# Google Backup Transport Security

Tags: android, security, encryption, drive, android-backup-service

I am trying to use Google Backup Transport.  Google transport stores into the user's app folder in their drive account which is a secure location, but there is a warning in their documentation.

> Caution: Because the backup transport can differ from device to
>   device, Android cannot guarantee the security of your data while using
>   backup. Be cautious about using backup to store sensitive data, such
>   as usernames and passwords.

Can anybody go into greater detail of what the security vulnerabilities are in this case?    What type of differences occur when transporting from different devices.

[link1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup)

[link2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup)